# Class with undetermined properties

Tags: typescript, dynamic, properties

I am trying to build a class that would accumulate values for rows and columns, each row/col identified by a string. I hope the code will be illustrative enough:

```
class TMatrix<TYPE>{

    [idRow: string]: { [idCol: string]: TYPE };

    fnset(nmRow: string, nmCol: string, value: TYPE ) {
      if (!this[nmRow]) 
          this[nmRow] = {};
      this[nmRow][nmCol] = value;
    }

    buildHtmlTable(){
    ...
    }
}
```

In fact the above code works but typescript complains in the methods:

> Property 'fnset' of type '(nmRow: string, nmCol: string, value: TYPE)
>   => void' is not assignable to string index type '{ [idCol: string]: TYPE; }'.ts(2411)

What may be a fix or the proper method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index signature must be compatible with ALL members of the type. This includes the methods of the class.

The best solution would be not to use the actual class to store these dynamic values. Use a separate dedicated object you can hold in a field. This avoids accidental overriding of class methods (someone could call `fnset('fnset', '', 0)` and override the `fnset method for example)

```
class TMatrix<TYPE>{

    data: { [idRow: string]: { [idCol: string]: TYPE } } = {};

    fnset(nmRow: string, nmCol: string, value: TYPE ) {
    if (!this.data[nmRow]) 
        this.data[nmRow] = {};
    this.data[nmRow][nmCol] = value;
    }

    buildHtmlTable(){

    }
}
```

If you really want to keep the data in the class you need to make the index signature compatible with all members:

```
class TMatrix<TYPE>{

    [idRow: string]: { [idCol: string]: TYPE } | TMatrix<TYPE>[keyof TMatrix<TYPE>]

    fnset(nmRow: string, nmCol: string, value: TYPE) {
        const data = this[nmRow];
        if (!data) {
            this[nmRow] = data;
        }
        if (typeof data === 'function') { // gurad agains overriding memebers, depeding on class memebers this may have to change to exclude other members, this works if you only have extra methods, no other fields
            throw  "don't override methods"
        }
        data[nmCol] = value
    }

    buildHtmlTable(){

    }
}
```